# Importing with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, maven

Is there a way to tell Tomcat to import a folder when starting so i can use it's content via tomcat . in my case the folder is the src/test/java that contain test classes .

i need to run the test classes using command line

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of tests? Integration tests?

Comment: Does that mean integration tests? Do you have selenium tests? What kind of application do you have? Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic thing is to use [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) to run the integration tests. In you case this means you need to have a separate maven-module (call it: mod-it) which contains the configuration for the integration tests. The best recommendation i can give is to use the [cargo2-maven-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) to start/deploy etc. Tomcat and deploy the war application within tomcat. Furthermore you should have a layout like this:

```
project
|-- mod-it
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- mod-war
|   |-- pom.xml
|   `-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- java
|       |   |   `-- com
|       |   |       `-- soebes
|       |   |           `-- wicket
|       |   |               |-- HomePage.java
|       |   |               `-- WicketApplication.java
|       |   |-- resources
|       |   |   |-- com
|       |   |   |   `-- soebes
|       |   |   |       `-- wicket
|       |   |   |           `-- HomePage.html
|       |   |   `-- log4j.properties
|       |   `-- webapp
|       |       `-- WEB-INF
|       |           `-- web.xml
..
`-- pom.xml
```

The [integration tests should be named like *IT.java](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) to get them run by the maven-failsafe-plugin

The best thing is to read [this example](http://khmarbaise.github.com/maui/it-example-container.html) which contains a complete example with Tomcat and cargo plugin. You can download the full example source incl. pom's etc. [here](http://khmarbaise.github.com/maui/examples.html).